# Remove hidden slicer

Tags: google-sheets, slicers

Due to the application of the slicer of the sheet, the slicer itself, that was on the right side of the first data rows of the table disappeared from my view.

How can I get it back or simply remove it?

I can create a new one, but I didn't find how to edit/remove the existing one!

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I manage to fix this issue like this:

1. Create a new slicer on the same table
2. Configure the slicer on the same column
3. In the slicer, `select all` items
4. All the rows are now visible!!
5. Remove the 2 slicers

Comment: Unfortunately, in some cases you can run into the "Two slicers can either have zero or all common rows," in which case it's not possible to add a new slicer to remove the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
function rem_slicer(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("YOUR SHEET NAME HERE");
  var slicers = sheet.getSlicers();
  slicers[0].remove();
}
```

After searching for the different solutions to remove hidden slicer, I've came up to the most effective one, with running this code, which is getting any hidden slicer and removing it even if you don't remember which column it was.

Comment: Code only answer are not the best way to help. Would be amazing if you could explain what are you doing, add a couple of comments if needed, spend some time articulating your train of thoughts. :)

Comment: added explanation. this code helps much more even when you don't know exactly where was the slicer.